# using ng-repeat to build a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-tables

I have a data structure like this:

```
{
  "Places to visit": {
    "Best": [
      "place1",
      "place2"
    ],
    "Worst": [
      "place3",
      "place4"
    ]
  },
  "Cuisines": {
    "Best": [
      "cuisine1",
      "cuisine2"
    ],
    "Worst": [
      "cuisine3",
      "cuisine4"
    ]
  },
  "Mobiles": {
    "Best": [
      "mobile1",
      "mobile2"
    ],
    "Worst": [
      "mobile3",
      "mobile4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Using this datastructure, I need to build a table in the UI which should look like this (with 2 indicators in one row).
[image]

I'm clueless on how to use ng-repeat on this data structure to get the desired table.

TIA.

Comment: Why `Cuisines` is on the same row as `Places to visit`?

Comment: That is how the designer wanted it to be, to get more indicators in one screen.. rather than a long scrolling page @AlonEitan

Comment: I voted to reopen since I was able to understand what the question was asking enough to write an answer that I think deals with the gist of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an html table, you'll need to reformat your data and probably want to use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` which allow multiple elements for a single item in your array.

As an example, a 'row' of data would have `a` as places to visit and `b` as cuisines:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th><th>best</th><th>worst</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>best</th><th>worst</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="row in vm.rows">
      <td rowspan="2">{{row.a.text}}</td>
      <td>{{row.a.items[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{row.a.items[2]}}</td>
      <td ng-if="row.b" rowspan="2">{{row.b.text}}</td>
      <td ng-if="row.b">{{row.b.items[0]}}</td>
      <td ng-if="row.b">{{row.b.items[2]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>{{row.a.items[1]}}</td>
      <td>{{row.a.items[3]}}</td>
      <td ng-if="row.b">{{row.b.items[1]}}</td>
      <td ng-if="row.b">{{row.b.items[3]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So each element of the 'items' array creates two table rows and contains 'a' and 'b' elements for the side-by-side items.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/JasonGoemaat/pen/BajKjPX)